# How to add a gesture detector to a view in Android

Tags: android, touch-event, gesturedetector

I was struggling with adding a gesture detector to a subview in my project. Do I override the parent's `onTouchEvent` or the child's `onTouchEvent`? Do I make an `OnTouchListener` and add the gesture detector there? The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) shows an example for how to add a gesture detector to the activity itself but it is not clear how to add it to a view. The same process could be used if subclassing a view (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20112261/3681880)), but I want to add the gesture without subclassing anything.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android) is the closest other question I could find but it is specific to a fling gesture on an `ImageView`, not to the general case of any `View`. Also there is some disagreement in those answers about when to return `true` or `false`.

To help myself understand how it works, I made a stand alone project. My answer is below.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This example shows how to add a gesture detector to a view. The layout is just a single `View` inside of an Activity. You can use the same method to add a gesture detector to any type of view.

[image]

We will add the gesture detector to the green `View`.

#### MainActivity.java

The basic idea is to add an [`OnTouchListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to the view. Normally we would get all the raw touch data here (like `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`, etc.), but instead of handling it ourselves, we will forward it on to a gesture detector to do the interpretation of the touch data.

We are using a [`SimpleOnGestureListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html). The nice thing about this gesture detector is that we only need to override the gestures that we need. In the example here I included a lot of them. You can remove the ones you don't need. (You should always return `true` in `onDown()`, though. Returning true means that we are handling the event. Returning false will make the system stop giving us any more touch events.)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this is the view we will add the gesture detector to
        View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

        // get the gesture detector
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureListener());

        // Add a touch listener to the view
        // The touch listener passes all its events on to the gesture detector
        myView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    }

    // This touch listener passes everything on to the gesture detector.
    // That saves us the trouble of interpreting the raw touch events 
    // ourselves.
    View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // pass the events to the gesture detector
            // a return value of true means the detector is handling it
            // a return value of false means the detector didn't 
            // recognize the event
            return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        }
    };

    // In the SimpleOnGestureListener subclass you should override 
    // onDown and any other gesture that you want to detect.
    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TAG","onDown: ");

            // don't return false here or else none of the other 
            // gestures will work
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onSingleTapConfirmed: ");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onLongPress: ");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onDoubleTap: ");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onScroll: ");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onFling: ");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It is a quick setup to run this project, so I recommend you try it out. Notice how and when the log events occur.

Comment: is it possible to detect the gesture on onCreate()? I cannot do operations in the MyGestureListener  class

Comment: my question is about your answer, so it will be hard to explain in a new post, I just meant to ask if its possible to override onScroll()/onLongPress()/onSingleTapConfirmed() in the oncreate() method and implement the methods there?

Comment: @Coder123, The methods you are talking about overriding are part of the SimpleOnGestureListener, so if you don't subclass that class (or the GestureDetector), I don't think there is a way to do it. Your only other option is to handle the events manually in the OnTouchListener.

Comment: This doesn't work on constraint layout or the linear layout or even empty views.

Comment: Returning `true` from `onDown` was the real trick. Spent whole night trying to figure out as to why the other events were not firing. Finally found the solution here. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

short version in kotlin to detect double tap only for a view:

```
val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(activity, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.d("myApp", "double tap")
        return true
    }
})
myView.setOnTouchListener { _, event -> gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) }
```

and don't forget to make `myView` clickable

Comment: Thanks. One small correction: onDown() needs to be overriden and return true otherwise it wont work