# How to detect a long touch to the screen of an android smart watch?

Tags: android, wear-os, ontouchlistener, wearables

I basically want to detect a long touch to my frameLayout, once detected I'll call an alert message that I have in a method.

```
    frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    first_tap = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    clicked = clicked + 1;
                    if (clicked == 2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(toolandmode.this, "Clicks:" + clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startTimer();
                    }
//                    else if (flag == 1)
//                    {
//                        Toast.makeText(toolandmode.this, "Clicks:" + clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        AlertMessage();
//                        flag = 0;
//                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

My activity contains a timer which I start by double tapping the screen but rather than making another double tap as the trigger for my Alert message I want to simply touch the screen for long then the Alert Dialog I made would be triggered. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you replace your current OnTouchListener code with a [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector) and a [SimpleOnGestureListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener). It supports both double tap and long press out of the box.

All you have to do is something like this:

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    public void onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        startTimer();
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        alertMessage();
    }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```

For more details on how to add a GestureDetector to a view you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054908/how-to-add-a-gesture-detector-to-a-view-in-android).